# PHP Script to Add One Every Hour

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm hoping to make a script where a user will get a "coin" every hour that they go on the page. For instance, if a user logs in twice during the same hour, they will only get one coin. But if they refresh the page during the next hour, they get another coin. However, they do not get coins when they do not refresh the page, even if many hours go by.

How would I even start going about doing this? Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: coins are temporary use or permanent?

Comment: Permanent. I want the user to have them even if they come back to the website many days from when they first use it. So if they visit the page every day, 3 times a day, they'll have 21 coins in a weeks time.

Answer (score 1):

Easy... :) If you are using MySQL or something to store the coins, get the time too, when the coin was credited. And each time the page is called, check the time. A pseudo code would be like this:

```
load(coins);
timeDiff = timeNow - timeLastCredited;
if (timeDiff > 1 hour)
  coins++;
save(coins);
```

In case of PHP, I guess you may do like this:

```
$coins = getCoins(); // Assuming this function will load the current coins count from DB.
$lastCredit = getLastCoinCreditedTime(); // Should return a DateTime integer.
$timeDiff = microtime() - strtotime($lastCredit);
if ($timeDiff > 60*60*60*1000)
  saveCoins($coins+1); // Assuming this function saves the new number of coins.
```

Comment: How would I save the current coins to a database and then get the value to display to the user on page load? I made a MySQL database and table with rows "coins" and "time". I don't have users or anything. Is that necessary? My code for putting coins in the database is

mysql_query("INSERT INTO flip (coins)
  VALUES ('$currentCoins')");

Where flip is my table, coins is the row, and my variable currentcoins is the coins for the person on the page. That is of course after I check the time, and if it is past an hour, I'll increment it by one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

On each page load (refresh, login, whatever), check to see if the user has already received a coin for the current hour. To do this, you need to know what the current hour is:

```
$hour = (new DateTime())->format("Y-m-d-h");
```

This will give a value like "2013-03-25-11" during the 11:00 hour. I'm including the date, since we don't to want skip giving a coin in, say, the 11 o'clock hour just because they were online yesterday at 11:05.

Then you can either:

1. Add one to their coin total whenever you have a new `$hour` value (ie. it's not recorded in your database) and save the `$hour` value, or
2. Save the `$hour` value in the database and count the total number of coins earned with a query like `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hour) FROM table;`

The first approach is useful if they're spending the coins on something (ie. you can add/subtract from their "coin account"); the second is useful if you just want a grand total of the number of coins (ie. the total number earned, ever).

Comment: using that line of code gives me arse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: Probably due to an older version of PHP - that syntax is only supported in more recent versions. Try $d = new DateTime(); $hour = $d->format("Y-m-d-h");

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have a users table in a database.

If that is the case, you can use a column in the database to update the latest time that a user has gone on the page with php and a query on that page. Then you can set up a cron job that runs every hour that will query the users table and see if the user has viewed the page within the last hour. If the user has viewed the page within the last hour, increment the amount of coins associated with that user.